# How to comply with Apache 2.0 requirement to state that changes have been made to a file

Tags: apache-2.0, license-notice

I have made a copy of an open source project that is licensed under the [Apache 2.0 license](https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html#apache-license-version-20), and I have made modifications to some of its files. I want to release my modified version to the general public.

According to the Apache 2.0 license clause 4(b):

> You must cause any modified files to carry prominent notices stating that You changed the files; and

How do I comply with the requirement to "carry prominent notices"?

All the files I modified have this header written by the original author of the project:

```
/*
 * Copyright 2018 Acme Corporation
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
```

What exactly do I add to this header such that it will carry a "prominent notice" that I have changed the file?

Answer (score 2):

Generally, adding your own copyright line is considered to be a prominent enough notice that you modified the file.

Thus, add a line `Copyright 2022 Flux` next to the existing line(s) that have the same form.

Comment: "Thus, add a line `Copyright 2022 Flux` next to the existing line(s) that have the same form" — Would that be above or below the `Copyright 2018 Acme Corporation` line?

Comment: Either side is good. I like to have the years in chronological order, so I would put it below. If there are already multiple copyright lines, keep the years in the same order.

Comment: I found a related question [Satisfying Apache 2.0 section 4.(b) when forking a project](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/12340/satisfying-apache-2-0-section-4-b-when-forking-a-project), but I don't think the answer there is correct.